# Unix file pattern issue: append changing value of variable pattern to copies of matching line

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a file with contents:

```
abc|r=1,f=2,c=2
abc|r=1,f=2,c=2;r=3,f=4,c=8
```

I want a result like below:

```
abc|r=1,f=2,c=2|1
abc|r=1,f=2,c=2;r=3,f=4,c=8|1
abc|r=1,f=2,c=2;r=3,f=4,c=8|3
```

The third column value is *r* value. A new line would be inserted for each occurrence.

I have tried with:

```
for i in `cat $xxxx.txt`
    do
        #echo $i
        live=$(echo $i | awk -F " " '{print $1}')
        home=$(echo $i | awk -F " " '{print $2}')

        echo $live
    done
```

but is not working properly. I am a beginner to `sed/awk` and not sure how can I use them.  Can someone please help on this?

Comment: your sample output doesn't match your description of "third column value is r value ,new line would be inserted for each occurrence" (IMHO). Consider reformatting your Q by using the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted code/data/output. Good luck.

Comment: I would use Perl to answer this; Python would do too; you could probably make `awk` do it.  I don't think it would be particularly sensible to try using `sed`.  The ```for i in `cat $xxxx.txt`; do …``` notation is not particularly sensible, either; with the 'power filters' being given the file to process rather than running a series of commands per line.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'[,;|]' '{c=0; 
                  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
                    if(match($i,/^r=/)) a[c++]=substr($i,RSTART+2);
                  delim=substr($0,length($0))=="|"?"":"|"; 
                  for(i=0;i<c;i++) print $0 delim a[i]}' file

abc|r=1,f=2,c=2|1
abc|r=1,f=2,c=2;r=3,f=4,c=8|1
abc|r=1,f=2,c=2;r=3,f=4,c=8|3
```

Comment: i checked but not working ,getting below error (i am trying on sunos.5.10)awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

Comment: Thanks for the replay but it is not working on sunos 5.10 getting below errors,                                                                                                 awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

Comment: Your awk may not be accepting multiple field separators. Check the version.

Comment: I am using sun Solaris 5.10.or an other version I need to check.

Comment: can you please help me any another way for ksh .

Comment: It's not shell specific it should work with any shell.  Default `awk` on Solaris is no good, however you may have `gawk` installed on some alternative directory.  Otherwise, set the FS to `|` and split first with `;`, then each element with `,` and follow the same logic.

Comment: yes, it has worked in sun Solaris 5.10 version with nawk and also one correction ($i,RSTART+3); instead of 2 I kept it for 3 because o/p was like =3,=2 and  I want 2,3.thnaks lot for the help and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Use an inner routine (made up of *GNU* `grep`, `sed`, and `tr`) to compile a second more elaborate `sed` command, the output of which needs further cleanup with more `sed`.  Call the input file "*foo*".

```
sed -n $(grep -no 'r=[0-9]*' foo | \
         sed 's/^[0-9]*/&s#.*#\&/;s/:r=/|/;s/.*/&#p;/' | \
         tr -d '\n') foo | \
sed 's/|[0-9|]*|/|/'
```

Output:

```
abc|r=1,f=2,c=2|1
abc|r=1,f=2,c=2;r=3,f=4,c=8|1
abc|r=1,f=2,c=2;r=3,f=4,c=8|3
```

---

Looking at the inner `sed` code:

```
grep -no 'r=[0-9]*' foo | \
     sed 's/^[0-9]*/&s#.*#\&/;s/:r=/|/;s/.*/&#p;/' | \
     tr -d '\n'
```

It's purpose is to parse *foo* on-the-fly (when *foo* changes, so will the output), and in this instance come up with:

```
1s#.*#&|1#p;2s#.*#&|1#p;2s#.*#&|3#p;
```

Which is almost perfect, but it leaves in old data on the last line:

```
sed -n '1s#.*#&|1#p;2s#.*#&|1#p;2s#.*#&|3#p;' foo
abc|r=1,f=2,c=2|1
abc|r=1,f=2,c=2;r=3,f=4,c=8|1
abc|r=1,f=2,c=2;r=3,f=4,c=8|1|3
```

...which old data `|1` is what the final `sed 's/|[0-9|]*|/|/'` removes.

Comment: thanks for the replay . i am trying given solution on sun os 5.10 KSH shell. not working getting error as invalid -o option for grep

Comment: @NileshChavan, drat, the `-o` is a *GNU* `grep` thing.  Sorry, I'll note that in the answer, then contemplate a workaround...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure `bash` solution. I wouldn't recommend actually using this, but it might help you understand better how to work with files in `bash`.

```
# Iterate over each line, splitting into three fields
# using | as the delimiter. (f3 is only there to make
# sure a trailing | is not included in the value of f2)
while IFS="|" read -r f1 f2 f3; do

    # Create an array of variable groups from $f2, using ;
    # as the delimiter
    IFS=";" read -a groups <<< "$f2"
    for group in "${groups[@]}"; do

        # Get each variable from the group separately
        # by splitting on ,
        IFS=, read -a vars <<< "$group"

        for var in "${vars[@]}"; do
            # Split each assignment on =, create
            # the variable for real, and quit once we
            # have found r
            IFS== read name value <<< "$var"
            declare "$name=$value"
            [[ $name == r ]] && break
        done

        # Output the desired line for the current value of r
        printf '%s|%s|%s\n' "$f1" "$f2" "$r"
    done
done < $xxxx.txt
```

---

Changes for `ksh`:

1. `read -A` instead of `read -a`.
2. `typeset` instead of `declare`.
3. If `<<<` is a problem, you can use a here document instead. For example:

   ```
   IFS=";" read -A groups <<EOF
   $f2
   EOF
   ```

Comment: thanks a lot it has worked for bash. but i am looking same for ksh,if any advice for ksh please help the same

Comment: If you need a `ksh` solution, tag your question with `ksh`, not `bash`. That said, use `read -A` instead of `read -a` and `typeset` instead of `declare` to make this work in `ksh`.

Comment: thanks for the KSH solution. I tried above changes for ksh but getting error as-syntax error at line 8 : `<' unexpected. is this because ksh version issue?

Comment: Possibly; `ksh` should support `<<<`.